# How can I blend two colors in CSS?

Tags: css, animation, blending

is there a way to retrieve a value of color from css blending two colors? For example I want to blend two divs and be able to set the blended value and on them to set the background colors of those two divs.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a example?

Comment: Something like on this page https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/ - the example with 3 circles. From blending they receive white color. I want to be able set this white color and by setting it receive the colors of those 3 squares

Comment: I guess to be more clear whats the use case? Are users going to be dragging these div around and mixing? do you have a static site and you just trying to style it? Frankly this question is confusing.Too many vague pronouns.

Comment: User will be able to set the finall color of blending and the app will show three colors from which user's color was made. E.g. User sets orange and the colors of div he will receive is red and yellow